# How to inject dynamic webpack bundle.js names into initial HTML rendering react component in Server Side Rendering?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I'm transforming a purely client side rendered React-Redux project to include server side rendering as well. 
According to the reduxJS manual (http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html) a typical boilerplate function that injects the initial component HTML and initial state into a template to be rendered on the client side looks like this:

```
function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
          // http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#security-considerations
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
        </script>
        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
}
```

So obviously at the end of the function a script-tag is including the bundle.js file for the client-side application.

Here comes my question:
What if my webpack doesn't simply create a single bundle.js but rather outputs a set of bundle files with dynamic file naming via the CommonsChunkPlugin like:

```
/bundle.32528d8bc783fafd2585.js  
/vendor.29ce638d0bba925f3e21.js  
/vendor2.da60e4a86c0ac5f28a03.js
```

How would I "dynamically" inject those files into the renderFullPage() function above replacing the `<script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>` tag?

Using HtmlWebpackPlugin templates doesn't seem to be an option here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, so not surprisingly it turns out that transferring a pure client side React App into a SSR React App isn't as straightforward as I thought it would be. There are many things to consider and was hard to find a tutorial that gives a good overview on Server Side Rendering. 
However, now there is one at UDEMY that I can really recommend. It's the most (or only) comprehensive one I've found so far for SSR beginners:

https://www.udemy.com/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux

Answer (score 0):

You should use this package: https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable
Import as script to html the smallest one with spinner for example and when loadable finish download finally bundle, change component.

Comment: Thanks, Ortee for your reply! React-Loadable seems to be great for doing component based code splitting but in case of my project would mean re-programming it entirely.  However, my multiple bundle files are only the result of splitting off vendor libraries. So I was hoping for an easier solution that doesn't require me to switch to component based code splitting at this point.